# CSS Grid dimensions & alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid, dimension

### Goal

I want a UI card component with the following spec:

Equal heights across multiple cards regardless of variations in content for:

- card
- card header
- card body

  - gauge (SVG element)

    - must align with the bottom of the gauge
  - table
- card footer

  - must align with the bottom of the card

### Problem

- Too much extra space is rendered between the body content and the footer such that the card is significantly taller than the card content.
- The extra space appears to come from `.card {grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) 3fr auto;}`, but changes to this have not been successful thus far.
- The extra space is most notable in full-screen when the viewport width is reduced and the cards wrap onto the next line.

```css
/*--------------------
Global
--------------------*/

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font: 1rem/1.5 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f1f2;
}

h1, h2, h3, p, table, svg {
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
}

table {min-width: 100%;}
th {text-align: left;}
td {text-align: right;}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*--------------------
Container
--------------------*/

main {
  align-content: safe center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

/*--------------------
Card
--------------------*/

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) 3fr auto;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card-header {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px red;
}

.card-header * {margin: 0;}

.card-header + .card-body {padding-top: 0;}

.card-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1fr;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px lime;
}

.card-body .gauge {
  display: grid;
  align-content: end;
  outline: solid 1px aqua;
}

.card-body .table {
  outline: solid 1px fuchsia;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px blue;
}

.card-footer * {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
        <p>Information text.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 4</th>
                <td>Td 4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 5</th>
                <td>Td 5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 4</th>
                <td>Td 4</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: OK. I think my question is illustrated if you Run the code snippet in full-screen and reduce the viewport size until just before the last card wraps onto the next line, i.e. the smallest viewport width where all cards are on one line. Where is all that extra vertical space coming from and how do I make the cards retain all their other alignments, but also only stretch to the card content?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, Try removing all the padding you have then take a screenshot and point out this space you're talking about. Also keep in mind you're working with a grid A single cell will define the width and height of all other cells within the same track (row/column)

Comment: Removing the padding just shifts the whole grid up by that amount of padding, but I will investigate if padding on the inner grid is affecting the calculation. Yes, you're right; it isn't clear what I'm asking. The behaviour was different within the web app where I was working; I was getting much more additional extra vertical space that didn't seem to relate to the content. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed paddings and margins, I think that now it is working

```css
/*--------------------
Global
--------------------*/

body {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

main {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;

}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font: 1rem/1.5 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f1f2;
}

h1, h2, h3, p, table, svg {
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
}

table {min-width: 100%;}
th {text-align: left;}
td {text-align: right;}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*--------------------
Container
--------------------*/

main {
  align-content: safe center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

/*--------------------
Card
--------------------*/

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) 3fr auto;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card-header {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px red;
}

.card-header * {margin: 0;}

.card-header + .card-body {padding-top: 0;}

.card-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1fr;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px lime;
}

.card-body .gauge {
  display: grid;
  align-content: end;
  outline: solid 1px aqua;
}

.card-body .table {
  outline: solid 1px fuchsia;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  outline: solid 1px blue;
}

.card-footer * {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
        <p>Information text.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 4</th>
                <td>Td 4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 5</th>
                <td>Td 5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 4</th>
                <td>Td 4</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 3</th>
                <td>Td 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <h3>Header content. </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="gauge">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
              <style>
                .circle-1 {
                  fill: #ccc;
                }
              </style>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,99.999995 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,0 100,100 0 0 1 200,100 l -100,0 z" class="circle-1" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 1</th>
                <td>Td 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Th 2</th>
                <td>Td 2</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <p><a href="#">Footer link</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```